# PHP mail() adding brackets in the from header

Tags: php, sendmail

I'm trying to send the alter the `from:` header in my email to match the corporate email standard within my origination. But this involves putting the department of the system within curly brackets.

The email is successfully sent with the header but ignores the department text and brackets within the header.

-Is there a way I can output this header without the brackers being ignored?

```
 $emailBody = "content test";
 $subject = 'subject test';
 $message = "<html><body>".$emailBody."</body></html>";
 $headers = 'From: System (department) <system@domain.org>' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

 $sendmail = mail('user@domain.org',$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Output:

```
 From: System
```

Desired Output:

```
 From: System (department)
```

Comment: don't use `mail()`. it's mickey-mouse garbage. use phpmailer or swiftmailer, both of which make it trivial to send a mime email with any `from` you want.

Comment: Im having issues sending mail with 'phpmailer'. It cant seem to find the mail server hosted in the cpanel or a test gmail. Whereas the built in `mail()` connects perfectly. What specifically makes `mail()` garbage?

Comment: rough analogy: mail() is a bullet that you fire with a rusty nail and a hammer, while phpmailer/swiftmailer are complete guns. it's very easy to screw up with  mail and cause security issues (header injections) or build a bad mime email.

Comment: Thanks, i will try 'phpmailer' again...i think smtp is disabled somewhere, but looks like its worth it in the long run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes (`"`) for name of user if you have spaces ( ) before  `<user@email.address>`.

`$headers = 'From: "System (department)" <system@domain.org>' . "\r\n";`

First email is your code without double quotes and second is my, with double quotes.

[image]